# How can I write the algorithm with cost and count using beamer?

Tags: beamer, algorithm2e

I want to make a `beamer` slide to show the running time calculation of algorithms, as shown in the figure. I use `algorithm2e`.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You could add it to the caption of as a comment.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example so we have a starting point.